# Unity analytics wrong report

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use this code for testing unity analytics:

```
void TestAnalytic()
{
    int count = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TestCounter", 0);
    Analytics.CustomEvent("Test", new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"Count",count}
        });
    count++;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("TestCounter", count);
}
```

and I called this method 5 times.
but unity analytic report this event 8 times and the "Count" show just one number (4) and (others).
Why is this happen?

Comment: As I am not sure yet about why it has been reported 8 times, the fact it shows 4 instead of 5 is because you increase `count` after creation the event instead of before. Is there anywhere else in your game where you send analytics reports?

Comment: Yes, you are right.but why other numbers didn't report?!
I send the report in each event of my game and I'm not sure to have a correct result!that's why I test it.

Comment: What I mean is that, are you sure you are not exactly using the line that send the analytics custom event elsewhere in your code, which would lead you to receive the 3 other unexpected events?

Comment: yes, I'm sure.I just set this custom event on a test button.